# How to record local information for later use JS

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm on a product registration site, and I need to copy the product information from that site and move on to another.

I'm a beginner, but the DOM manipulation issues to get the information I know and I can do it normally.

However, as it is more than one product, I am using ForEach to get the information ... However, I do not know how to store it for later on the other site I copy it.

It follows in a way I tried:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require ('fs-extra') 

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.wavenfe.com.br/');
  await page.type('#logarEmail', user, {delay: 100})
  await page.type('#logarSenha', password, {delay: 100})
  page.click('#logar')
  await page.waitForSelector('#container > div.menu_servicos > div > div.box_menu_servicos > h2 > a')
  await page.click('#container > div.menu_servicos > div > div.box_menu_servicos > h2 > a')
  await page.waitForSelector('#produto')
  await page.click('#produto')
  const resultado = await page.evaluate(() => {
  document.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) > span > a').forEach((element, index) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        element.click()
        return {
          codigoProduto: document.querySelector("#txtProdCodigo").value,
          descricaoProduto: document.querySelector("#txtProdDesc").value
        };

      }, 1000 * index)
    })
    console.log(resultado)
  })
  })();
```

Does anyone have any ideas or anything that can help me on how I can store this information for later recording on another website?

Remembering that there are more than 10 products that I want to copy ...

Comment: You have `resultado` so seems like you're storing it there. Please explain why this isn't what you wanted.

Comment: This is not what I want, because with ForEach JS accesses more than 10 products ... So in this ForEach loop it always replaces the value of the variables.

So I wouldn't be able to use it to move to another site ....

I want to find a solution to this

Comment: Yes!!! Translate

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but I don't see a `forEach` and I still have no idea what data you want or what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry ... I edited the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `.forEach` by `.map` it will return an array with all your informations inside